# Generating PDF user password hash

Tags: pdf, encryption, hash

Currently, I am attempting to generating a hash of a user password for PDF, given the encrypted PDF file and the plain password. I follow the instruction of this [article](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Edst/Adobe/Gallery/anon21jul01-pdf-encryption.txt). However, the hash I've computed is different from the hash stored in the PDF file.

> The hashed user password (/U entry) is simply the 32-byte padding
> string above, encrypted with RC4, using the 5-byte file key. Compliant
> PDF viewers will check the password given by the user (by attempting
> to decrypt the /U entry using the file key, and comparing it against
> the padding string) and allow or refuse certain operations based on
> the permission settings.

First, I padded my password **"123456"** using a hardcoded 32-byte string, which gives me

```
31 32 33 34 35 36 28 BF 4E 5E 4E 75 8A 41 64 00
4E 56 FF FA 01 08 2E 2E 00 B6 D0 68 3E 80 2F 0C
```

I tried to compute the hash with RC4 using the 5-byte file key as the key. According to the article:

```
The encryption key is generated as follows:

    1. Pad the user password out to 32 bytes, using a hardcoded
       32-byte string:
           28 BF 4E 5E 4E 75 8A 41 64 00 4E 56 FF FA 01 08
           2E 2E 00 B6 D0 68 3E 80 2F 0C A9 FE 64 53 69 7A
       If the user password is null, just use the entire padding
       string.  (I.e., concatenate the user password and the padding
       string and take the first 32 bytes.)

    2. Append the hashed owner password (the /O entry above).

    3. Append the permissions (the /P entry), treated as a four-byte
       integer, LSB first.

    4. Append the file identifier (the /ID entry from the trailer
       dictionary).  This is an arbitrary string of bytes; Adobe
       recommends that it be generated by MD5 hashing various pieces
       of information about the document.

    5. MD5 hash this string; the first 5 bytes of output are the
       encryption key.  (This is a 40-bit key, presumably to meet US
       export regulations.)
```

I appended the hashed owner key to the padded password, which gives me

```
31 32 33 34 35 36 28 BF 4E 5E 4E 75 8A 41 64 00
4E 56 FF FA 01 08 2E 2E 00 B6 D0 68 3E 80 2F 0C
C4 31 FA B9 CC 5E F7 B5 9C 24 4B 61 B7 45 F7 1A
C5 BA 42 7B 1B 91 02 DA 46 8E 77 12 7F 1E 69 D6
```

Then, I appended the /P entry (-4), treated as a four-byte integer, encoded with little endian, which gives me

```
31 32 33 34 35 36 28 BF 4E 5E 4E 75 8A 41 64 00
4E 56 FF FA 01 08 2E 2E 00 B6 D0 68 3E 80 2F 0C
C4 31 FA B9 CC 5E F7 B5 9C 24 4B 61 B7 45 F7 1A
C5 BA 42 7B 1B 91 02 DA 46 8E 77 12 7F 1E 69 D6
FC FF FF FF
```

Last, I appended the file identifier to it. The trailer of my PDF is:

```
trailer
<<
/Size 13
/Root 2 0 R
/Encrypt 1 0 R
/Info 4 0 R
/ID [<B5185D941CC0EA39ACA809F661EF36D4> <393BE725532F9158DC9E6E8EA97CFBF0>]
>>
```

and the result is

```
31 32 33 34 35 36 28 BF 4E 5E 4E 75 8A 41 64 00
4E 56 FF FA 01 08 2E 2E 00 B6 D0 68 3E 80 2F 0C
C4 31 FA B9 CC 5E F7 B5 9C 24 4B 61 B7 45 F7 1A
C5 BA 42 7B 1B 91 02 DA 46 8E 77 12 7F 1E 69 D6
FC FF FF FF B5 18 5D 94 1C C0 EA 39 AC A8 09 F6
61 EF 36 D4 39 3B E7 25 53 2F 91 58 DC 9E 6E 8E
A9 7C FB F0
```

MD5 hashing this block of data returns `942c5e7b2020ce57ce4408f531a65019`. I RC4-ed the padded password with [cryptii](https://cryptii.com/) using the first 5 bytes of the MD5 hash as the key. However, it returns

```
90 e2 b5 21 2a 7d 53 05 70 d9 5d 26 95 c7 c2 05
6e 2a 28 40 63 e7 4a d4 e9 05 86 71 43 d1 39 d6
```

while the hash in PDF is

```
58 81 CA 74 65 DC 2E A7 5D D2 39 D4 43 9C 0D DE
28 BF 4E 5E 4E 75 8A 41 64 00 4E 56 FF FA 01 08
```

Which step am I doing wrong? I suspect that the problem happens because

- I am appending the File Idenifier in a wrong format
- I am using the wrong drop bytes with RC4.
- The hash function is not for PDF 1.6
- I make some mistake during those process
- Or maybe the article is actually wrong

Files: Original PDF [dummy.pdf](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf), [dummy-protected.pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FXbK75T3L2sWJueOjQTe-e6ypL-5v5pq/view?usp=sharing) (Password: 123456)

Please help

Comment: Can you share the PDF in question?

Comment: Sure, I've put the link in the updated question

Comment: The issue is probably due to different versions: The article refers to PDF version 1.3, while your document was created with PDF version 1.6. According to [this](https://www.pdflib.com/pdf-knowledge-base/pdf-password-security/encryption/), the algorithms (and presumably the encryption details) are different.

Comment: I think you are right, where can I find the password hashing detail for >V1.3 PDF?

Comment: Maybe this link is interessting: https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/contrib/doc/specs/software/adobe/pdf/PDFReference16-v4.pdf, chapter *3.5.1. General Encryption Algorithm*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues in your calculation:

- The article to use refers to PDF encryption algorithms available for PDF-1.3 but your document is encrypted using an algorithm introduced with PDF-1.5.
- You make an error when appending the file identifier - actually only the first entry of the **ID** array shall be appended, not both (which is not really clear from the article you use).

In a comment you asked accordingly

> where can I find the password hashing detail for >V1.3 PDF?

I would propose using the PDF specification, ISO 32000.

As ISO specifications go, they are not free, but Adobe used to provide a version of ISO 32000-1 with merely the ISO header removed on their web site. Some days ago it has been removed (By design? By error? I don't know yet.) but you still find copies of it googl'ing for "PDF32000".

The relevant section in ISO 32000-1 is 7.6 *Encryption* and in particular 7.6.3 *Standard Security Handler*.

Following that information you should be able to correctly calculate the value in question.

(Alternatively you can also use old Adobe PDF references, the editions for PDF 1.5, 1.6, and 1.7 should also give you the information required for decrypting your document. But these references have been characterized as *not normative in nature* by prominent Adobe employees, so I would go for the ISO norm.)

Beware, though: After ISO 32000-1 had been published, Adobe introduced an AES-256 encryption scheme as an extension which obviously is not included in ISO 32000-1. You can find a specification in "Adobe Supplement to ISO 32000, base version 1.7, extension level 3".

Furthermore, with ISO 32000-2 that Adobe AES-256 encryption scheme and all older schemes became *deprecated*, the only encryption scheme to use with PDF-2.0 is a new AES-256 encryption scheme described in ISO 32000-2 which is based on the Adobe scheme but introduces some extra hashing iterations.